# Deploying a Static website on Server

Tags: deployment, web, subdirectory

I am trying to built a static website using godaddy server. I created a folder say Manage inside public_html in which there is an index.php. Now when I am trying to open this page on browser with URL "www.mysite.com/Manage/index.php" It is showing error, File not found, 404 error. So what possible error I might be making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first look to error.log. If you use nginx find in /var/log/nginx, if httpd in /var/log/httpd.

And what do you mean about "static"? PHP preprocessor generate html from *.php files, so you index.php is not static.

For this case you need to setup [LAMP](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/lamp-package-setup.html) stack.

Comment: Yes, looking into error.log helped me solve this problem. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few reasons. If you are using an RHEL-based distribution for your server, you need to edit the master Apache configuration file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf` and change two things:

Change `UserDir disabled` to `UserDir disabled root`
If `#UserDir public_html` is commented change it to `UserDir public_html`

This tells Apache that the directory containing each user's html files is a subdirectory of their home directory called public_html.

You may also need to change the permissions of your user directory and your `public_html` directory to allow Apache to read and execute inside them. To do this, run the following commands:

```
sudo chmod o+x /home/myusername
sudo chmod o+rx /home/myusername/public_html
```

Restart Apache and see if it works.

The source for this knowledge is not my brain. It comes from the wonderful course at Washington University in St. Louis [CSE 330](https://classes3.engineering.wustl.edu/2017/fall/cse330/index.php?title=CSE_330_Online_Textbook_-_Table_of_Contents) Rapid prototype development.